# What is the 'best' way of communicating with small microcontrollers/devices?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, wireless, communication

var best = "simple & cheap";

I have a server in my apartment that I have an XBEE hooked up to. I use it to communicate with another XBEE plugged into an Arduino. I am trying to hook up many things to my server, but I don't want to have 10 XBEEs hooked up to 10 Arduinos, because that's expensive. I also don't want to have wires running all over the place to hook up sensors/etc to my one Arduino.

My first thought was to buy some Arduino Minis, and wire something like these to them:
[RF Link Transmitter](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10535)
[RF Link Receiver](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10533)

Would there be a betters solution? Do you have any particular resources I should go read? The endpoint devices would have to do things like read sensors, trigger switches, and even display data. Also, I'm not sure if I would use batteries for these or try to get power adapters for these.

Please comment if I should include more information about anything! :)

Comment: [Similar](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/25196/wifi-module-with-mcu-on-one-board)

Comment: Try the **Jeenode**, arduino based boards with radio links for cheap. Jeelabs has an amazing blog and tons of examples and info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bluetooth LE (Low Energy) is actually perfect for this type of application. It's meant for low power and low bandwidth communication needs, where each device only needs to send very small bursts of information periodically. It's also very highly optimized to run off of coin cell batteries so you might not need AC adapters if the sensor's duties are simple enough. We recently did a project that used lots of Bluetooth LE beacons and each one lasted for about 2 months off of a coin cell battery.

The hardware we used was already built for us but there are BLE solutions for the Arduino:
http://www.adafruit.com/products/1697

Best part is you can use it with any device that has Bluetooth 4.0! (iPhone, Android phone, BT 4.0 dongle). And you'd only need one receiver since Bluetooth is already highly optimized to share the RF spectrum.

I used this book to get acquainted with BLE, it was pretty useful (very detailed but you can skim through what you need):
http://amzn.com/013288836X

One important thing to note if you want to use Android: There was a rather annoying bug with its BLE implementation so you need the latest Android (4.4.3) to get the best results. Although, it only affects you if you have tons (over 2000) unique BLE device IDs floating around (which can happen if some devices want to rotate their MAC address for privacy reasons).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was thinking about staying away from Bluetooth. I'm not going to be using bluetooth devices to connect to the endpoint devices. I was wanting to stick to regular RF com because of its cost and range. Also, I would only consider a battery option if it lasts for like a year.

Comment: Depending on the usage scenario you can get a year out of BLE devices with a few AA batteries.

Comment: @AndrewKoroluk If you want simple and cheap, this is the best way to go, it is supported on many platforms and by lots of different hardware and is well supported by OEM's. Any RF solution will require you to maintain custom hardware, drivers, etc because there is no standard for RF communications. If you want something working *today* for very little money and minimal effort drop a BT LE on it and call it a day.

Comment: And to clarify, bluetooth *is* RF, but it has a standard defined communication stack. If you use raw RF transponders you will have to design your own communication stack (which means drivers and arduino code). And you will not be winning much in terms of power. LE is designed for low power! Why not trust an entire industry of engineers to provide a better solution to what is an uninteresting interface problem in your device?

Comment: If you read the comments on [one of the pages you linked to](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10533) you'll see mostly negative comments -- users are having all sorts of issues.  In addition, if you want to have multiple transmitters and just one receiver, you are going to have to design some sort of collision avoidance scheme to deal with more than one transmitter trying to send at the same time.  And with just one way communication, the sender has no way of knowing if the message got through.  All in all, the "simple RF scheme" is *not recommended*. Go with BLE.

Comment: The thing is I'm not worried about the software. I'm a software developer by day. What I'm really trying to ask is if there is a better solution than Arduino mini + RF link modules, especially a cheaper one with similar functionality.

Comment: @AndrewKoroluk , read my [answer to another question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/76812/1729) there is MUCH more to designing a robust RF interface than you think., The rflink module gives you a receiver and transmitter, nothing more. It is up to you to design and implement a communication system that is robust enough for your use. If you want multiple devices this means collision detection, packet-encoding, all kinds of messy stuff. Sure there are some libraries already written, but it is still a TON of work for something that is already done for you!

Comment: You still need other hardware to do encoding/decoding, frequency multiplexing and a bunch of other things that already implemented for you in BT LE. Of course, if the goal is to learn how to do this, there are certainly ways to make it work, if the goal is "simple and cheap" as you state in *the first sentence of your post* this is not the way to go.